# Dexie IndexedDB Combine multiple Where with anyOf and toArray

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have a Dexie/IndexedDB query where I need two selection criteria.

I want to know if the fk_dog is equals any value in an array, this works fine:

```
        const children = await theTables.runTable
          .where('fk_dog')
          .anyOf(this.dogIDs)
          .toArray()
        console.log("children: ", children)
```

However, I also want to query by currentEventID, but I don't know how to add this in the where clause.

I've tried .and, but that doesn't seem to work.

So basically I need to combine the above with the below:

```
onst bings = await theTables.runTable
        .where({
          fk_event: this.currEventArray[0].currentEventID, 
          })
          .toArray()
```

It's probably a simple thing but I haven't been able to find the solution by Googling. I'm using Quasar/Javascript for the code.